# Specialization of a template with enable_if in header file

Tags: c++, templates, header, specialization, enable-if

So i want to make 2 functions: one for numbers(with template) and one for strings.
Here's my best try:

*Header:*

```
class myIO
{
public:

    template<class Arithmetic,
        class = enable_if_t< is_arithmetic_v <Arithmetic>>
    >
    static Arithmetic Input();

    template<>
    static string Input<string, void>();
};
```

*cpp:*

```
template<class Arithmetic, class>
static Arithmetic myIO::Input()
{
    Arithmetic x;
    //...
    return x;
}

template<>
static string myIO::Input<string, void>()
{
    string x;
    //...
    return x;
}
```

This implementation works but if i want to use it with `string` i have to do `string x = myIO::Input<string, void>();`

And i would like to be able to write just `<string>` not `<string, void>`

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer:
*.h:*

```
class myIO
{
public:

    template<class Arithmetic,
        class = enable_if_t< is_arithmetic_v <Arithmetic>>
    >
    static Arithmetic Input();

    template<class String,
        class = enable_if_t< is_same_v<String, string> >
    >
    static string Input();
};
```

*.cpp:*

```
template<class Arithmetic, class>
static Arithmetic myIO::Input()
{
    Arithmetic x;
    // doing something
    return x;
}

template<class String, class>
static string myIO::Input()
{
    string x;
    // doing something
    return x;
}
```

*p.s. i have actually tried a similar method - `enable_if_t< typeid(String) == typeid(string), string >` - but it didn't work*

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
class A {
    public:
    template<typename T, typename U>
    static void func()
    {
        std::cout << "Do stuff\n";
    }

    template<typename T>
    static void func()
    {
        A::func<T, void>();
    }

};

int main()
{
    A::func<string>();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Or even `template<typename T, typename U = void>` ...  I couldn't get the code posted by the OP to compile.